# How to make appengine push-to-deploy work with github submodules?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Initially, private repos on github created under an organization were not accessible from GAE. To everyone's merriment this just started working a few days ago.

So PtD works fine for repos that don't have a submodule. Is there any way to make GAE pull the submodule(s) as well?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the --recursive flag ?

Examples : git clone --recursive URL